# cannot open source file d3dx10.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have just made a project in visual studio 2012 ultimate. Within that project and its source files, I added a main.cpp and tried to do

```
#include <d3dx10.h>
```

I get the error

```
cannot open source file d3dx10.h
```

I am using windows 10 so isn't DirectX shipped with the include?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 includes the Windows 8 SDK which provides the DirectX headers and libraries, but does *not* include deprecated helper utility code. The D3DX utility library (D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11) is deprecated as is the legacy DirectX SDK itself. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

**The best recommendation is to use Direct3D 11 instead of Direct3D 10. Direct3D 11 fully replaces Direct3D 10 on all supported platforms, can work on a more broad range of video hardware, and has a full suite of open source utility code replacements.**

[Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)
[Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/)
[DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/)
[DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog/)
[Direct3D Feature Levels](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/)

> In a similar vein, I'd recommend using VS 2015 rather than VS 2012 which comes with the Windows 8.1 SDK. There have been a lot of C++11 language improvements and bug fixes since VS 2012.

If required, you can mix the legacy DirectX SDK with the Windows 8 SDK that comes with VS 2012 or later, but you need to reverse the include/lib paths from the traditional order. There are also a few other quirks that you can work around.

For x86/Win32 configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
```

For x64 native configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```